# How to adjust distance of pie chart value boxes?

Tags: coldfusion, zingchart, coldfusion-2016

Update: Looks like the default value box distance I am seeing is specific to ColdFusion 2016's version of zingcharts as the chart lays out differently when I try to replicate the issue in the latest version of zingcharts. We are probably going to just switch our CF chart usage to a js library directly.

I am trying to replicate the style of a pie chart from another system in zingcharts. The last piece that I can't figure out is how to adjust the distance of value boxes around a pie chart. They are quite far right now and make the pie chart smaller unnecessarily.

[image]

The [value box documentation](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/graphset/plot/value-box/) led me to try using offset adjustments but offset-x and offset-y don't work because the value boxes can be in any direction from the pie. I tried offset, padding and margin adjustments but nothing appears to work.

Is there any attribute that will allow for a value box "distance" or alternative approach? Doesn't appear a trigonometric formula is possible here but correct me if I'm wrong.